# How does the Try Galaxy Progressive Web App is able to use the whole screen and even the menubar or battery bar in PWA mode?

Tags: ios, web-applications

[Try Galaxy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek4ZB.jpg)As you can see in the image, it is using the whole top portion of the screen even when it is just a progressive web app. How!?

I googled for the answer and also went through apple keynote to find an answer and was unable to find one.